# How to sum CPU usage value of processes name in Powershell

Tags: powershell, process, sum, aggregate-functions

I have a powershell script to check CPU Usage of process in Window.

```
$Output=""
$Processes = (get-wmiobject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process) 
foreach($Process in $Processes)
{
    $Output += $Process.name + "=" + $Process.PercentProcessorTime + " "
}
Write-Host "${Output}"
```

I ran it. The result have many same process name.
Ex:

```
chrome=0 chrome#1=0 chrome#2=0 chrome#3=0 chrome#4=0 chrome#5=0 chrome#6=0 chrome#7=0 chrome#8=0 chrome#9=0 PUTTY=0 chrome#10=18 chrome#11=0
```

I want to list all process and CPU Usage of them as in picture.
And same process will be sum.

[image: 1]

I want to sum value same process as below:

```
$Processes = get-process | Group-Object -Property ProcessName
$Output="OK |"
foreach($Process in $Processes)
{
    $Obj = New-Object psobject
    $Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $Process.Name
    $Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Mem -Value ($Process.Group|Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum
    $Output += $Process.Name + "=" + $($Process.Group|Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum +" "
}
Write-Host "${Output}"
```

And result is sum of same process:

```
armsvc=1736704 ASDSvc=11309056 audiodg=18563072 bash=1323008 calc=4136960 chrome=2138599424
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Processes = (get-wmiobject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process) 

$procStrings = @()
$Processes | %{  New-Object psobject -Property `
     @{ Time = $_.PercentProcessorTime; 
        Name = ($_.name -replace "#\d+", "" )}}`
 | ?{ $_.Name -notmatch "_Total|Idle" } `
 | Group-Object Name `
 | %{ 
    $procStrings += "$($_.Name)=$(($_.Group | Measure-Object Time -Sum ).Sum)"}

$procStrings -join " "
```

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating together a string (of text) rather than adding up the total.

This will give you the total process processor usage.
*Note: the total will be greater than 100%, because the output also includes the `_Total` and `Idle` (bot 100% on my machine)

```
$Output=0

$Processes = (get-wmiobject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process) 
foreach($Process in $Processes)
{
   $Output += $Process.PercentProcessorTime 
}
Write-Host "Total Processor Usage: $Output %"
```

Example output:

> Total Processor Usage: 318 %

### Edit

This should output something similar to what you see in the task manager.

```
$Processes = (get-wmiobject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process) 

$Processes | %{  New-Object psobject -Property `
     @{ Time = $_.PercentProcessorTime; 
        Name = ($_.name -replace "#\d+", "" )}}`
 | ?{ $_.Name -notmatch "_Total|Idle" } `
 | Group-Object Name `
 | %{ New-Object psobject -Property `
      @{ Name = $_.Name; 
         Sum = ($_.Group | Measure-Object Time -Sum ).Sum }} `
 | Format-Table
```

Comment: Now, this format as a line, a line:
Name            Sum
----                  ---
System           1
smss               0
csrss              2
wininit             0
services         0
lsass              0
lsm                 0
svchost           6

Can you help me to format it to only aline as below:

System=1 smss=0 csrss=2 wininit=0 services=0 lsass=0 lsm=0 svchost=6

Comment: @thach.nv92 No. You should ask (or search for) another question on how to format piped output in powershell. Think how this question may help someone else with a similar problem. What you are asking is too specific. Also this is really something you need to learn. If we solver the whole problem you wont be able to solve the next problem you have. Have a look at my answer and try and understand what each line is doing. It is painful now but it will be better in the long run trust me.

Comment: @Mr.DarcyThomas I try it but can't solve it. Can you help me?